# MongoDB Stitch collection watchers

Tags: java, android, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

Does anybody know if MongoDB team plans to incorporate collection listeners on the Stitch Java SDK anytime soon? Without this feature, I cannot completely do a migration from FirebaseDB, where I am now stuck at the point of replacing Firebase stream listener implementation. This is for my Android application. If Atlas were free completely, I could have done the polling by myself knowing that I wouldn't be charged for the transactions. Or, is this something available today via a hack?

Comment: Hey Konjengbam, what kind of functionality would expect from the listeners? Something along the lines of https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events ? Stitch Android SDK doesn't have this functionality yet but we're always working on new features and it's good to know what kind of "live" features users expect. Do you want single document listeners or a whole collection (which may be big in MongoDB)?

Comment: Single document listener is my priority. I would love to have collection listeners as well. Would you be able to share when this could come along?

Comment: @edaniels Thanks. Yes, something along the lines of that firebase link. What I have decided to do in the interim is to use Chinese based push notifications to tell clients that a document changed.

Answer (score 0):

As learnt, it is a feature in request and hopefully, MongoDB team will offer event listeners in one of the upcoming updates.